# Why is this function undefined when I run `go test`?

Tags: go

Here is the code

a.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Haha() {
    fmt.Println("in Haha")
}

func main() {
}
```

a_test.go

```
package main_test

import "testing"

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    Haha()
}
```

`go build` works. But when I run `~/gopath/src/zjk/misc$ go test -v`. Here is what I get

```
# zjk/misc_test
./a_test.go:6: undefined: Haha
FAIL    zjk/misc [build failed]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you have different packages

should be:

a.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Haha() {
    fmt.Println("in Haha")
}

func main() {
}
```

a_test.go

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    Haha()
}
```

output:

```
# zjk/misc_test
in Haha
PASS
ok      github.com/qwertmax/so  0.009s
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `import "main"` in `main_test` package & call it like `main.Haha()`.

Just to elaborate why one might have the tests for a package under a different package, I should say there are two categories of tests:

- First, those tests that supervise the implementation of a package, the internals, to assure it's integrity, resource usage profile and performance benchmarks and the like. These tests should reside alongside the package code itself.
- Second are those that test the functionality and usage of the package. In these tests, we want to assure a package stands up to it's claims about the service it provides. An important aspect of these tests is that they assure that we are not exposing any unnecessary details; to ensure private parts remain private and public API is crystal clear. That's why these tests should reside in another package, under a different name, to act as a consumer of the package under the test.

One exception is package `main` which is not meant to be used from inside other packages, so we just write all tests inside the package itself (as @kostya commented).

Comment: I don't think this applies to `package main`.

Comment: Sometimes you **must** use external tests to avoid circular imports. (In my opinion tests should generally be external (which some people call *black box tests* though that is confusing see http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2013/11/unit-tests-white-box-testing.html) to avoid fragility.

Comment: @AndrewW.Phillips You are right - and probably I should spend some time on improving this answer. Regarding black-box vs white-box testing, IMO it's orthogonal to the approach we take. I tend to prefer an outside-in approach which indeed favors external tests - and in most cases leads to white-box testing (personally I prefer black-box testing a tiny bit more. Though it doesn't mean I avoid white-box testing).

Answer (score 1):

Your test is in a package called `main_test` and the function is in a package called `main`. You are not importing `main`, so there's no way to address it.

If your test can't be in package `main`, move the function to a third package.